How do I make the tab view menu disappear?
Trying to make the ‘More…’that appears in a tab view disappear. On the screen, I don’t want the More option or for the user to access anything else. In SwiftUI
I tried the code that is already on the site For making the tab view disappear. It did not work. I am using a fullscreen tab view. If there is a better way to write it, I am open to listen.

Don't add the tabs that trigger "more".
